# Missing something in config not able to access ssh/ping from other vlan or network

Tags: cisco

I am confused, how come this is not working.. only thing i want to access the asa management from 10.109.32.6.0

I have remote asa.there is a mpls link between both sites. I am behind 10.109.32.6 and asa is behind 10.109.35.11.asa and mpls route is connected (VLAN2 10.4.1.0) see below configuration, any suggestion what i am doing wrong?  I have added additional config to allow ping and ssh from my site

```
ssh VLAN12 255.255.255.0 inside
ssh 10.109.32.6 255.255.255.192  MPLS  http server enable
http VLAN12 255.255.255.0 inside 
http 10.109.32.6 255.255.255.192 MPLS  icmp permit any inside 
icmp permit any MPLS 
 inspect icmp 
  inspect icmp error 
    name x.x.x.x InternetGateway description Internet Gateway 
    name x.x.x.x IS description Fidelity Information Systems MPLS IP Range 
    name 10.109.0.0 MPLS description MPLS IP Range 
    name 10.4.3.3 MPLSGateway description MPLS Gateway 
    name 10.5.1.0 VLAN12 description Internal user LAN 
    name 10.4.3.0 VLAN80 description MPLS third party network 
    ! 
    interface Ethernet0/0 
    !  
    interface Ethernet0/1 
     switchport access vlan 3 
    !
    interface Ethernet0/2 
     switchport access vlan 2 
    !  
    interface Ethernet0/3 
    !
    interface Ethernet0/4 
    !
    interface Ethernet0/5 
    !
    interface Ethernet0/6 
    !
    interface Ethernet0/7 
    !
    interface Vlan1 
     description Internal LAN 
     nameif inside 
     security-level 100 
     ip address 10.5.1.1 255.255.255.0 
    ! 
    interface Vlan2  
     description Internet Access 
     nameif outside 
     security-level 0 
     ip address x.x.x.x x.x.x.x 
    ! 
    interface Vlan3 
     description LaSer Group MPLS 
     no forward interface Vlan2 
     nameif MPLS 
     security-level 0 
     ip address 10.4.1.4 255.255.255.0 
    ! 
    ftp mode passive 
    clock timezone GMT/BST 0 
    clock summer-time GMT/BDT recurring last Sun Mar 1:00 last Sun Oct 2:00 
    dns server-group DefaultDNS 
     domain-name X.X.X.X 
    object-group network gMPLS 
     description MPLS Destinations 
     network-object MPLS 255.255.0.0 
     network-object IS 255.255.0.0 
    access-list inside_nat_outbound_1 remark Traffic to internet hidden behind  X.X.X.X 
    access-list inside_nat_outbound_1 extended permit ip VLAN12 255.255.255.0 any 
    access-list inside_nat_outbound remark Traffic to MPLS hidden behind  10.109.35.11 
    access-list inside_nat_outbound extended permit ip VLAN12 255.255.255.0  object-group gMPLS 
    pager lines 24
    logging asdm informational 
    mtu inside 1500 
    mtu outside 1500 
    mtu MPLS 1500  
    icmp unreachable rate-limit 1 burst-size 1
    no asdm history enable 
    arp timeout 14400  
    global (outside) 1 X.X.X.X netmask 255.0.0.0 
    global (MPLS) 2 10.109.35.11 netmask 255.0.0.0 
    nat (inside) 2 access-list inside_nat_outbound 
    nat (inside) 1 access-list inside_nat_outbound_1 
    route outside 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 InternetGateway 1 
    route outside 0.0.0.0 255.255.255.255 InternetGateway 255 
    route MPLS MPLS 255.255.0.0 10.4.1.1 1
    route MPLS IS 255.255.0.0 10.4.1.1 1
    timeout xlate 3:00:00 
    timeout conn 1:00:00 half-closed 0:10:00 udp 0:02:00 icmp 0:00:02 
    timeout sunrpc 0:10:00 h323 0:05:00 h225 1:00:00 mgcp 0:05:00 mgcp-pat 0:05:00
    timeout sip 0:30:00 sip_media 0:02:00 sip-invite 0:03:00 sip-disconnect 0:02:00 
    timeout sip-provisional-media 0:02:00 uauth 0:05:00 absolute 
    timeout tcp-proxy-reassembly 0:01:00 
    timeout floating-conn 0:00:00 
    dynamic-access-policy-record DfltAccessPolicy
    aaa authentication ssh console LOCAL 
    http server enable 
    http VLAN12 255.255.255.0 inside 
    no snmp-server location 
    no snmp-server contact 
    snmp-server enable traps snmp authentication linkup linkdown coldstart 
    crypto ipsec security-association lifetime seconds 28800 
    crypto ipsec security-association lifetime kilobytes 4608000 
    telnet timeout 5 
    ssh VLAN12 255.255.255.0 inside 
    ssh 10.109.32.6 255.255.255.192 MPLS 
    ssh timeout 5 
    console timeout 0 

    dhcpd auto_config outside 
    !
    dhcpd address 10.5.1.5-10.5.1.254 inside 
    dhcpd dns 1.1.1.1 1.1.1.1 interface inside 
    dhcpd domain xxxx interface inside 
    dhcpd enable inside 
    !

    threat-detection basic-threat 
    threat-detection statistics access-list 
    no threat-detection statistics tcp-intercept 

    !
    class-map inspection_default 
     match default-inspection-traffic 
    !
    !
    policy-map type inspect dns preset_dns_map 
     parameters
      message-length maximum client auto 
      message-length maximum 512 
    policy-map global_policy 
     class inspection_default 
      inspect dns preset_dns_map 
      inspect ftp 
      inspect h323 h225 
      inspect h323 ras 
      inspect rsh 
      inspect rtsp 
      inspect esmtp 
      inspect sqlnet 
      inspect skinny 
      inspect sunrpc 
      inspect xdmcp 
      inspect sip 
      inspect netbios 
      inspect tftp 
      inspect ip-options 
    ! 
    service-policy global_policy global 
    prompt hostname context 
    no call-home reporting anonymous
```

Comment: Did you generate a crypto-key for the firewall?

Comment: OK, now that I've embarrassed myself, do any warnings appear in the ASA log?  Are you sure your traffic is getting to the ASA?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is directly from cisco's website:

```
 hostname(config)# crypto key generate rsa modulus 1024
 hostname(config)# write memory
 hostname(config)# aaa authentication ssh console LOCAL
 WARNING: local database is empty! Use 'username' command to define local users.
 hostname(config)# username exampleuser1 password examplepassword1
 hostname(config)# ssh 192.168.1.2 255.255.255.255 inside
 hostname(config)# ssh timeout 30
```

You have to generate a crypto key AND an allowed IP address for SSH in order to access a firewall via SSH. On routers, you have to create a username and password and create an SSH key. I do not see a crypto-key.

What is your IP address? You say you are "behind" 10.109.32.6 but unless you have that address or are part of VLAN12, you will not be able to access the firewall.

http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/security/asa/asa84/configuration/guide/asa_84_cli_config/access_management.html#wp1503771

Comment: Hal, I  dont think crypto is the issue, i have removed some info from config, regarding 10.109.32.6. i am NAT behind this address, my real ip is 10.30.0.0 network . that vlan12 is name of  10.5.1.0 network at remote location internal address

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe ping will ever work.  It is disabled on these security devices by design.  As for SSH, it is possible to do from the OUTSIDE - connect to the public IP of the device.  You simply need to configure it.  Tons of config examples online, e.g. [this link](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/security/asa-5500-x-series-next-generation-firewalls/118075-configure-asa-00.html).  If all fails, reboot the thing and try it then (5 max concurrent connections may be hung sessions?)

Comment: Ron, do you know whats wrong in my configuration? Because i already have configured ssh allow..

Comment: Try adding "ssh 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 outside".  It looks like you have restricted SSH access to a subset of possible host as the config is shown.  Google for ASA SSH configuration example site:cisco.com.

Comment: I'd agree with Ron, as a basic test permit everything to SSH. If that works, then you just need to narrow it down. If that doesn't work, look elsewhere.